# Voted on more questions than there are

Tags: support, questions, voting

So on my Electorate Badge progress on [IoT stack exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com), it says that I have voted on 303 questions.  I can believe that; I'm a very active user, and have almost definitely seen all the questions that have gone on the site so far.

If you check out this screenshot:

[image]

... you see that there are 313 questions total on the site.  Still works, right?  303 questions voted on, 313 questions total.

What doesn't make sense is that I've posted 12 questions on the site.  A bit of math for the mathematically challenged:

```
303 + 12 = 315
```

... which is greater than the number of questions on the site.   What's going on here?

Comment: It possible those 2 are deleted questions

Comment: You can audit your votes in your profile page, under the votes sub-tab.

Comment: The 303 is *upvotes* on questions. There are also votes for closing, reopening, deleting and undeleting posts.

Comment: @anonymous2... You can break it down by doing a search for *is:q deleted:all* to get the total questions on the site deleted or not. Or replace all with 0 or 1 for not deleted or deleted accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess there are some posts deleted. Those are not in the total question count, but you can have cast a vote on them.

---

A quick peek in the API (using our own [SQL engine](https://online-sql-editor.com/stack-exchange/com/stable/Sql)) yields 125 questions on IoT, so quite likely you voted on deleted posts.

Query:

```
select count(*) from posts where post_type = 'question'
```

Comment: Why is the downvote necessary? This is the only logical reason for the numbers to be off.

Comment: No idea.  It seems right.  Thanks for the info!  BTW, I'm not sure what the link is supposed to link to, but it just yields a login page that produces nothing but an error for me.

Comment: Okay. That shouldn't happen. You can execute SQL there just like SEDE.

Comment: Okay, seems to be working now.  Not sure what was going on before.